# Views date filter by year - only one select list for the year

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have a content type "news" and a views page to list the news. The views contains a exposed filter (category and year).

How can I realize the select list "Year" with the follwing options as exposed filter:

- All
- 2016
- 2015
- 2014
- 2013
- 2012

When the user selects '2015' the list below is updatet (ajax) and only news entry form 2015 are listed.

How can I realize this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add filter criteria of **Year** field.
2. Now expose this field by selecting 'Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it' option from field setting.
3. For Ajax behaviour, choose **Use AJAX** from advance view section.

Comment: Okay, thank you. There is no field year but a field "date" and the granularity can be set to "year".  The question is now how to change the order of the select list entries vom "2010, 2011, 2012 ..." to "2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, ...". Is this possible to change the order of the exposed select list??? Howß

Comment: Use form_alter hook.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: See my answer below for a screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Using Views, you will need to use a contextual filter based on the year. For the exposed filter, I have utilized the settings for the date like so:

[image]